# Let gitolite use automatically LDAP pub keys

Tags: ssh, ldap, gitolite

All the public keys of our users are in our LDAP. Gitolite already gets the usernames and groups out of this LDAP. But for each new user, we have to manually add the userkey to the keydir of gitolite.

Is there a way of letting gitolite automatically get the keys directly from LDAP?

Comment: What schema do you use to hold the keys?

Comment: They are saved in the sshRSAAuthKey attribute field of the user. I know how to query them, but I don't know how to let gitolite query them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the gitolite gets the users from the authorizedkyes file. This file is generated when you add a new public key to the keys folder.

You have to configure your ssh to use external command for authorized keys file. From *OpenSSH **6.1*** you can use *AuthorizedKeysCommand* (for the external command) and *AuthorizedKeysCommandUser* (under the id the command will run). You have to write your own script or adjust one from the internet to provide the proper output. The command takes one option (uid) and give back the list of public keys ot the user.

If you check the authorized keys of the gitolite it looks more advanced.

```
command="/usr/share/gitolite/gl-auth-command username",no-port-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-pty ssh-rsa AAAAB3Nza
```

So you have to adjust your script to generate such an output if the user match with your gitolite user (normally git or gitolite).